# Camel Endpoint with dynamic header

Tags: apache, apache-camel, endpoint

I am trying to send sftp call through endpoint and need to pass header as one of the parameters. Can some on help me out on this.
My route will be looking like this

```
<route id="sftCall" autoStartup="true">
<from uri="sftp://{{host}}//{{Directory}}/${header.date}?password=banksftp.password}}&amp;privateKeyUri=//{{privateKeyUri}}&amp;scheduler=quartz2&amp;scheduler.cron={{Scheduler}}&amp;disconnect=true&amp;noop=true"/>
<log message="Ends...${header.CamelBatchSize}"/>
</route>
```

Another route will be like

```
<route id="route">
<from uri="timer"/>
<setHeader headerName="date">
<simple>20170512</simple> 
</setHeader>
<to uri="direct:sftpCall"/>
</route>
```

Thanks,,

Comment: try this `<route id="route">
<from uri="timer"/>
<setHeader headerName="date">
<simple>20170512</simple> 
</setHeader>
<to uri="direct:sftpCall"/>
</route>`

Comment: sorry pvpkiran My bad, whatever u suggest that is how i'm using and my problem with setting header in from uri

Comment: You mean to say, in your sftpCall route you cannot access the date header which you are setting in other route? instead of variable date try using something else. forexample myDate

Comment: I tried that to and it does not solve my issue

Comment: would you mind explaining what is happening now? Is your sftpCall route getting called?

Comment: whenever trying to send ${header.date} as value to from uri, it is consider as path directly instead of taking header.date value. this is the issue currently i'm facing

Comment: try `${in.header.date}`

Comment: I tired that way it is showing as "Caused by: [org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException - Cannot change directory to: ${in.header.date}]"

Answer (score 2):

Your setup has multiple issues. Where to begin best?

- The first route is an **SFTP poller**. That means it receives a message whenever a **new file is available** on the sftp server in the given directory. That's fine, but...
- Your SFTP poller has a dynamic expression as subdirectory (`${header.date}`). As far as I know you **cannot have a dynamic `from` address** in a Camel route. Because this would mean that you could consume from multiple endpoints.
- In your example the SFTP poller would have to scan whatever subdirectories on the server. To achieve that you have to remove the part `${header.date}` and set the **`recursive` option**.
- The second route is timer based a sends messages to `direct:sftpCall`. This means to a route that begins with `from uri="direct:sftpCall"`. But **you don't have such a route**.

I guess that with `<to uri="direct:sftpCall"/>` you want to call the SFTP route that has `sftpCall` as route id. But that does not match the destination route at all.

- `direct` is the "protocol" (synchronous in-memory call). But your destination route uses the protocol `sftp`
- `sftpCall` is a route id. You cannot call a route by its ID (as far as I know)

If my guess is correct and you want that **your timer route triggers your sftp route**, the timer route has to **upload a file** to the sftp-server/directory the sftp route consumes. That would simply look somehow like this.

```
<to uri="sftp://{{host}}//{{Directory}}..."/>
```

Comment: Thank you burki, this give me some clarification for my issue and one thing i need to know can I directly call **<from uri="sftp://{{host}}//{{Directory}}/${header.xxx}"** like this, having header.xxx in sftp endpoint

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 misconception

> 1. Use of header in from endpoint definition

- In/Out header is a part of exchange object and exchange object is create by existing route (naturally)
- The `from` endpoint definition is fixed once the route is created

For your route definition, `${header.date}` will be use as a hard code string path because there is no exchange object when the spring create the route.

> 2. Use of direct component

The [direct](http://camel.apache.org/direct.html) component is used to connect existing routes in the same camel context, not to kick start/build another route.

---

**If you are uploading files to sftp server**, then you only need the timer route and paste your `sftp` component string in the `to` endpoint definition and use [toD](http://camel.apache.org/message-endpoint.html) or [Recipient List](http://camel.apache.org/recipient-list.html) instead of `to`.

**If you are downloading files from sftp server**, then you need to use RouteBuilder to create route and [ControlBus](http://camel.apache.org/controlbus-component.html) to start/stop created route.